# Convert flatfile dates into timestamp

Tags: sql, informatica

How do I convert below time format which is coming from flatfile into timestamp it has an extra 'T' in it which I want to remove

2016-06-23T13:09:31.0000000

Comment: It would be nice to know which SQL dialet or server you are using and to have some details about the context of the operation, like for example I load the data into a text column of a temporary / import table and then using a select into or I am using the value from a string value within my Java program and composing an insert statement .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query in expression:

TO_DATE(REPLACECHR(1,SUBSTR('2016-06-23T13:09:31.0000000',0,19),'T',' '),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS')

In date part you will have to pass the date_column.